# Email without user intervention

Tags: android, email

I want to create an app which sends a file from my android phone (Sony SP) via E-mail.
(Actually I am working with a tutorial, but it doesn't work the way it is supposed to)

I used the following code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.jebinga.andruino;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Mail m;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        m = new Mail("myEmailAdress.gmx.at", "myPassword"); 

    }

    public void sendEmail(View view){
        String[] toArr = {"otherEmailAdress"}; 
        m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
        m.setFrom("myEmailAdress"); // who is sending the email 
        m.setSubject("Betrefff"); 
        m.setBody("Hallo"); 


        try { 
            m.addAttachment("/storage/sdcard0/testordner/testdatei.txt");  // path to file you want to attach
            if(m.send()) { 
                // success
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
                // failure
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            // some other problem
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Mail:

```
package com.jebinga.andruino;



import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
    private String _user; 
    private String _pass; 

    private String[] _to; 
    private String _from; 

    private String _port; 
    private String _sport; 

    private String _host; 

    private String _subject; 
    private String _body; 

    private boolean _auth; 

    private boolean _debuggable; 

    private Multipart _multipart; 


    public Mail() { 
        _host = "smtp.gmx.com"; // default smtp server 
        _port = "25"; // default smtp port 
        _sport = "25"; // default socketfactory port 

        _user = ""; // username 
        _pass = ""; // password 
        _from = ""; // email sent from 
        _subject = ""; // email subject 
        _body = ""; // email body 

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
    } 

    public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
        this(); 

        _user = user; 
        _pass = pass; 
    } 

    public boolean send() throws Exception { 
        Properties props = _setProperties(); 

        if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
            } 
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

            msg.setSubject(_subject); 
            msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

            // setup message body 
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

            // Put parts in message 
            msg.setContent(_multipart); 

            // send email 
            Transport.send(msg); 

            return true; 
        } else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
    } 

    private Properties _setProperties() { 
        Properties props = new Properties(); 

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

        if(_debuggable) { 
            props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
        } 

        if(_auth) { 
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
        } 

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

        return props; 
    } 

    // the getters and setters 
    public String getBody() { 
        return _body; 
    } 

    public void setBody(String _body) { 
        this._body = _body; 
    } 

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        this._to = toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        this._from = string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        this._subject = string;
    }

    // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jebinga.andruino"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.jebinga.andruino.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log:

```
05-11 18:15:18.465: E/Trace(18257): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-11 18:15:18.465: D/ActivityThread(18257): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
05-11 18:15:18.465: D/ActivityThread(18257): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
05-11 18:15:18.465: D/ActivityThread(18257): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
05-11 18:15:18.745: I/Adreno200-EGL(18257): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
05-11 18:15:18.745: I/Adreno200-EGL(18257): Build Date: 05/29/13 Wed
05-11 18:15:18.745: I/Adreno200-EGL(18257): Local Branch: SoMC_Viskan
05-11 18:15:18.745: I/Adreno200-EGL(18257): Remote Branch: 
05-11 18:15:18.745: I/Adreno200-EGL(18257): Local Patches: 
05-11 18:15:18.745: I/Adreno200-EGL(18257): Reconstruct Branch:
```

If i press the button the mail should be sent.
But i get the toast of the exception: There was a problem sending the email.

---

Update

```
05-11 18:49:26.961: E/Trace(25053): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-11 18:49:26.961: D/ActivityThread(25053): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
05-11 18:49:26.971: D/ActivityThread(25053): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
05-11 18:49:26.971: D/ActivityThread(25053): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
05-11 18:49:27.201: I/Adreno200-EGL(25053): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
05-11 18:49:27.201: I/Adreno200-EGL(25053): Build Date: 05/29/13 Wed
05-11 18:49:27.201: I/Adreno200-EGL(25053): Local Branch: SoMC_Viskan
05-11 18:49:27.201: I/Adreno200-EGL(25053): Remote Branch: 
05-11 18:49:27.201: I/Adreno200-EGL(25053): Local Patches: 
05-11 18:49:27.201: I/Adreno200-EGL(25053): Reconstruct Branch: 
05-11 18:49:33.588: D/com.jebinga.andruino.MainActivity(25053): Problem...
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053): I got an error
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1126)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at com.jebinga.andruino.Mail.send(Mail.java:106)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at com.jebinga.andruino.MainActivity.sendEmail(MainActivity.java:45)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3666)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4171)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17186)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
05-11 18:49:33.618: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(25053):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do not just display a Toast. Log the exception to LogCat. Then, examine the Java stack trace and fix whatever problem you have.

Comment: So i added logs now addidionally to the toasts, but hhow do i go on with examining the stack trace? Sorry i am not very good in programming so far...

Comment: Ok, i guess i got it so far (see update), but I don't really know what to do with this

Comment: You're trying to send the mail on the main thread. That's not allowed in newer android version. Create an extra thread for that.

Comment: I added the following code to the onCreate Method to solve  onNetworMainThreadException.
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: @jebinga that's a really bad idea. You should use and AsyncTask instead.